# How do you save data input into a macro so that the input form can be populated with the data next time it runs?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to save data that was input into a Microsoft Word form in VBA after the macro terminates. I have a form that has about 40 fields with names, addresses, phone numbers etc and I don't want the user to have to input everything again in case they realize that they made a mistake and need to change 1 item. Currently, the macro deletes all the data that was input into the form when the form closes.

I've looked around on forums and Google but haven't had any luck.

This code brings up my input form from a word document with a command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    InputForm.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

This code closes the form:

```
Private Sub CloseForm_Click()

    Dim Closing As Integer
    Closing = MsgBox("This will exit the form and erase all the data that has been input. You may want to review the documents to ensure they were generated correctly before closing the form. Click Yes to proceed to close the form or No to go back to the form.", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Exit Confirmation")
    If Closing = vbYes Then
        Unload InputForm 'This closes the Input Form and returns the user to Word
    End If
End Sub
```

The macro does not save the information input into the form. Whenever it closes, all the information is erased; I want it saved.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends

Comment: Have you given any thought as to where the data should be saved? We have no idea what's feasible in the business scenario where this is used.

Comment: The macro will need to be accessed via a cloud server, so I would like for the data to be saved in the same document that has the command button that brings up the macro.

Comment: Remember: If you want to "ping" someone you need to use @ + UserName. For example @Stomper. Otherwise, we get no notification that you've replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options for saving data in the document

1. `Document.Variables` This has been available in Word since the very early days and is available in all versions since Word 2.0 (early 1990s). It's simply a place to store any number of strings, associated with an identifier (name). In essence, a key-value pair. Important to note: It must be a pair, there cannot be a key without a value and a value cannot be a zero-length string. Assigning a value to a name creates the `Variable`; deleting the value removes the `Variable`. These are not visible to the user.

Example:

```
Document.Variables("Name").Value = "John Doe"
```

2. `Document.CustomDocumentProperties` Similar to `Variables` but data-types other than strings are available. There is a limit to the length of the data that can be stored. They are visible to the user through the "Properties" interface. They must be explicitly created / destroyed. This was introduced in, I believe, Word 97.

Example:

```
Document.CustomDocumentProperties.Add(Name As String, LinkToContent As Boolean, _
                                      [Type], [Value], [LinkSource])
```

3. `CustomXMLParts` These are XML "pages" saved in the docx zip package. This is a good way to save data, and it's easily accessible from the *closed file*. The capability was introduced in Word 2010, so won't be available in older versions nor in doc file formats, only docx.

The coding is more complex than for `Variables` or `Properties`.

The usual way to work with this in the described scenario is to create the CustomXMLPart in the document (or template - documents created from the template should carry over the CXP). Then all the code needs to do is read/write from the xml nodes already available. If the VBA coder has no background in XML parsing there will be a steep learning curve.

There are many ways to go about reading and writing, here's a snippet that demonstrates the basics of reading, to give an idea of what's involved:

```
Sub ReadCXP()
    Dim cxp As Office.CustomXMLPart, CXPs As Office.CustomXMLParts
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim sUri As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    'object, not collection, because ID is unique and can return only one
    'ID is unique to each CustomXMLPart - this is won't work as it stands!
    Set cxp = doc.CustomXMLParts.SelectByID("{32B20BB8-F4FB-47D6-9DF4-FFAF5A1D8C18}")

    Dim xmlNds As Office.CustomXMLNodes
    Dim xmlNd As Office.CustomXMLNode
    Set xmlNds = cxp.SelectSingleNode("trees").ChildNodes
    For Each xmlNd In xmlNds
        Debug.Print xmlNd.XML
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know any XML parsing so I'd prefer to do option #2, since I need to save values other than strings, including check boxes.  I've tried using the above code in my macro but I can't seem to get the syntax right as VBA is not recognizing what I input, which I can tell because the when I type 'Document.' the .CustomDocumentProperties doesn't show up. 
The name of my input form is InputForm and the name of the doc that calls InputForm is named InputDocumentMacro. The name of one of the variables that I want to save is ClientName, but I also need to save check box values, such as POACheck1

Comment: I also need to know how to retrieve the data when the macro opens again.

Comment: Hey @Stomper :-) The request in your comment is a bit of a dilemna - I think it would be best to formulate this very precisely in a new question. I debated quite a while before composing my answer - the original question borders on being "too broad" for the site (see the [help]). But the topic is useful, so I decided to answer the stated question - how to save data for a future time. But if you try to *change* the question, at this point, it definitely becomes too broad... and you're changing the question after an answer has been posted, which site rules also do not allow...

Comment: ... In writing a new, more narrowly targeted question you also have the opportunity to show the code you've tried and provide more exact details (a [mcve]) which will enable people to write a better answer :-)

Comment: Hey @Cindy Meister, I'm using the 2nd option but am having difficulty. My code is:
ActiveDocument.CustomProperties.Add Name:="ClientName", LinkToContent:=False, Value:=ClientName, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString

Sometimes the code works and sometimes it gives me the following error: Run-time error '-2147467259) (800004005'); Automation error Unspecified error. I have checked the variables that I am trying to write to the properties part of the word document and they do have values. I know it's not much to go on, but can you shed some light? Let me know if this should be a separate question.

Comment: @Stomper - It would help if this were a new question because then you can provide more context. For example, what the content of `ClientName` is, under what conditions the code runs and any pattern you can detect as to when the code fails. A [mcve], as it were.

Comment: I've gotten the code more or less working thanks so much! However, it is intermittently failing to save the data by some of the users at my company. While inputting data, if they click on a window other than the input form, like Adobe or another Word document and then go back to my Input Form to update the data and then click the button that closes the form and is supposed to save the data, sometimes the new info is not saved. Do you have any suggestions/ideas? Here's a Code ex.
.Add Name:="AgentMale1", LinkToContent:=False, Value:=MaleAgent1.Value, Type:=msoPropertyTypeBoolean